# Scale all flexbox containers equally

Tags: css, flexbox, box

Trying to have all flex boxes inside my flex containers scale equally.

[image: Here's an image of the webpage]

If you try and reduce the viewport, the center flexbox will start to resize, but the outer ones do not. So you end up with a situation where you have a tiny image in the center with massive images on the sides.

I've only just started learning CSS, so I'm not entirely sure what I am doing so I appreciate any help.

Here are a few extra images that help illustrate the issue:

Before reducing viewport:
[image: Before reducing viewport]

After:
[image: After reducing viewport]

So ideally I want the images on the outside to scale down alongside the image in the center.

```css
.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #808080;
}

.flexbox-inner {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 720px;
  margin: 0px 32px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  background-color: #808080;
}

.flexbox-outer {
  width: 192px;
  height: 1148px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  background-color: #808080;
}

.flexbox-outer-inner {
  width: 160px;
  height: 558px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
}

.flexbox-outer-inner-bottom {
  margin-top: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div class="flexbox-outer">
    <div class="flexbox-outer-inner"></div>
    <div class="flexbox-outer-inner flexbox-outer-inner-bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox-inner"></div>
  <div class="flexbox-outer">
    <div class="flexbox-outer-inner"></div>
    <div class="flexbox-outer-inner flexbox-outer-inner-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Stephen I think you're looking for something called relative length units. Could you use the edit button bottom left of your question and add in more details about precisely how you want boxes to grow and shrink as the viewport changes - I'll start writing an answer for you

Comment: @ZachJensz I've edited to include two extra image that better illustrate what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Check [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) for *Absolute length units* and *Relative length units*. As you are using *Absolute length units* in your sizes there is no way the Flexbox Layout mechanism can resize your image containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could use relative length units, in this case percentages:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #808080;
}

.flexbox-inner {
  width: 60%;
  height: 720px;
  margin: 0px 32px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  background-color: #808080;
}

.flexbox-outer {
  width: 20%;
  height: 1148px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  background-color: #808080;
}

.flexbox-outer-inner {
  width: 90%;
  height: 558px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
}

.flexbox-outer-inner-bottom {
  margin-top: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div class="flexbox-outer">
    <div class="flexbox-outer-inner"></div>
    <div class="flexbox-outer-inner flexbox-outer-inner-bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox-inner"></div>
  <div class="flexbox-outer">
    <div class="flexbox-outer-inner"></div>
    <div class="flexbox-outer-inner flexbox-outer-inner-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @zachjenz Thank you for the help. It definitely allows it to scale based on the viewport, width wise at least. Though it does make it so the container no longer centers properly.

An additional question however, is there a way I could figure out how to scale the height with the width to keep a constant aspect ratio of the flex box?

Comment: @zackjenz I think I've figured something out with some googling. I found people using padding to retain aspect ratios of containers and it seems to be working. Just trying to figure out the ratios for my outer flexboxes.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I was wondering if you could point me in some sort of direction. I have my initial boxes set up and they scale as I want them now, but I want to start putting some content below it, but the initial container is quite large so any text I type starts quite far down the page. Is there anything I can do to help? I've tried using relative sizes on the initial container, but that messes up everything inside and even then it doesn't bring the text below the container up any further.

Thanks for any help you can provide. @ZachJensz

Comment: @Stephen Forget the padding hack, just use the `aspect-ratio` property